# MongoDB Queries Are Slow, Despite Having Index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a nodejs/mongoose(MongoDB) setup that I use to store my old homework assignments and other documents, along with a score for importance on each.

There's an endpoint to search through the stored documents and display the 10 most relevent results ranked by importance (rank).

The query usually takes longer than the browser will allow and results in a timeout. There's roughly 5k documents and the following is the query and I have ran createIndex on the fields I am querying.
Any tips on improving the query speed would be appreciated.
Index created with: `db.searchresults.createIndex(text: "text");`

```
const regex = new RegExp(query, 'i');
SearchResults.find({text: {$regex: regex}})
                .sort( { rank: "desc" } )
                .limit(10)
                .lean().exec(function(error, results){
    ...});
```

Comment: A text index like that will not be used by a regex operation. What is a sample `query` (regex) being used here?

Comment: a sample `query` value would be a single word ie "algorithm" without quotes. What sort of query should be used against a text index?

Comment: [`"$text"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

Comment: Found the proper syntax to use the $text operatator @rickhg12hs mentioned, thanks. `find({ $text: { $search: query }` it will perform the query successfully, but it does take almost a full minute to complete, is that normal?